# The Galois extension over a functional field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, reference-request, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}(t)$ be the function  field over the complex field. As we know $X^{n} - t $ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$, I think  for that reason it has cyclic galois extension  for any $n$.
Can you suggest  me some reference  for this topic " Galois extension over the functional  field ".

Answer (score 1):

$X^n - t$ factorizes as $(X - t^{1/n}) (X - \zeta_n t^{1/n}) \cdots (X - \zeta_n^{n-1} t^{1/n})$ over $\Bbb C(t^{1/n})$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n$<sup>th</sup> root of unity, so $\Bbb C(t^{1/n}) / \Bbb C(t)$ is normal.

Any automorphism must send $t^{1/n}$ to $\zeta_n^r t^{1/n}$ for some $r$, which defines a (non-canonical) isomorphism $\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb C(t^{1/n}) / \Bbb C(t)) \cong \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

---

For references:

- [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177962/91375), which cites:
- [Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/galois-groups-and-fundamental-groups/2511B1C10ACF174A0F444A045D9C1F89) by Tamás Szamuely, whose Theorem 3.4.8 (attributed to [Adrien?] Douady) says:
  $$\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{\Bbb C(t)} / \Bbb C(t)) \cong \widehat{F}(\Bbb C)$$

where $\widehat{F}(\Bbb C)$ denotes the "free profinite group on the set of complex numbers".